# Power set of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me with a proof that the power set of real numbers is strictly larger than the set of real numbers? I have been finding it hard using Cantor's general proof in this special case. A reference or answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Voting to migrate to Math Stack Exchange, where such questions belong. You will probably need to describe what the problem is in more detail, because probably someone will just recite Cantor's proof for general sets $X$, which presumably you know (?) according to your post.

Comment: @Mario What's the problem with using Cantor's argument for this special case?

Comment: The general argument works exactly the same on every set $X$. It's not clear why the proof would even need a "special case."

Answer (score 4):

This is a special case of the more general result that there is no bijection between any set $X$ and its power set. If you're going to prove it about reals then you might as well prove it about an arbitrary set.

The idea is similar to that of [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument). Suppose there is a bijection $f : X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$, and consider the set
$$A = \{ x \in X : x \not \in f(x) \}$$
This is certainly a subset of $X$, and so $A = f(y)$ for some $y \in X$.

But something went wrong... is $y \in f(y)$? Is $y \not \in f(y)$?

Comment: Or, if you want a more "direct" proof, show that there is no surjection from $X$ to $\mathcal P(X)$ by taking any map $f : X \to \mathcal P(X)$ and constructing an element of $\mathcal P(X)$ not in its range.  Of course, it is the set $A$ defined above.

Answer (score 0):

Cantor’s theorem can also be proved for the set of real numbers ( $\mathbb{R}$ ) and the power set of real numbers ( $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ )based on a contradiction.

We want to prove $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is of greater cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$.

We assume that there is a function $f$ that can map every element of $\mathbb{R}$ to every element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ (in other words function $f$ is bijective. Which means it is both injective and surjective).

First, we prove $f$ is injective, which means every element of $\mathbb{R}$ is mapped to some unique element in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$). Now, this should be obvious by the definition of power set. As the $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ contains all possible subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, which include a singleton subset per each element of $\mathbb{R}$, there is one to one correspondence between each and every singleton subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$  and each and every element of $\mathbb{R}$, which means $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ should have at least the $ |\mathbb{R}| $ (Minimum cardinality that  $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ could be of is $|\mathbb{R}|$ ) (Vertical bars signify cardinality). So we have proved that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$ is not less than $|\mathbb{R}|$.

Now we should prove $f$ is not surjective. But remember we have assumed $f$ is surjective. That is because we are looking for a contradiction which we can then use to prove that our original assumption is wrong. So as our next step, we construct a special subset of $\mathbb{R}$, called $S$, that contains only those elements of $\mathbb{R}$ that are not mapped to themselves by $f$. Now we ask: does $S$ belong to the image of $f$? That is, is there some element of $\mathbb{R}$ that $f$ maps to $S$? If $f$ is surjective, meaning it covers all possible subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (=all possible elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$), then the answer should be yes. But whichever element we pick, we get a contradiction. Suppose we pick $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = S$. Then we have two possibilities: either $x \in S$ or $x \notin S$. If $x \in S$, then by the definition of $S$, $x \notin f(x)$. But $f(x) = S$, so $x \notin S$. This contradicts the assumption that $x \in S$. If $x \notin S$, then by the definition of $S$, $x \in f(x)$. But $f(x) = S$, so $x \in S$. This contradicts the assumption that $x \notin S$. So either way, we get a contradiction. This means that our initial assumption that $f$ is surjective must be wrong. There is no function that can map every element of $\mathbb{R}$ to the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$.

We have earlier proved that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})| \nless |\mathbb{R}|$, and now we have proved that no function can map every element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$) to $\mathbb{R}$, which means $|\mathbb{R}| \neq |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$. Combining these two proofs we can conclude that there must be some elements left in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ unmapped. Therefore, there are more elements in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ ( =subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ ) than $\mathbb{R}$, meaning the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is greater than that of $\mathbb{R}$. This proves Cantor’s theorem in the context of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

***Actually, this is equivalent to proving Cantor’s theorem for any set and its power set. Only the symbols of sets are changed to reflect the set of real numbers ( $\mathbb{R}$ ) and the power set of real numbers ( $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ ) in this proof. Cantor’s theorem applies to any set and its power set irrelevant of size or cardinality. It is even valid for the empty set and its power set too.***

Note: This entire proof is based on the fact of the existence of non-self-referenced elements in the image of $f$ (in the power set) or the absence of such elements as the concept of an empty set. If not for the empty set concept deeply embedded within axioms of set theory, the power set of a set with only a single element would have been almost identical eg. if $A = \{1\}$ then $P(A) = \{\{1\}\}$. As a result, a function mapping $A$ to $P(A)$ would have had no non-self-referenced elements. Therefore, the basis of our proof would have been rendered invalid. But in set theory, we take the empty set as a possible choice or an implicit subset of $A$, meaning $P(A) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$. Therefore Cantor's theorem is still valid for any set and its power set.

*In the context of OP's specific question, it doesn't matter the scale of the cardinality of a set (finite, countably infinite, or uncountably infinite) as cardinality is defined based on the one-to-one correspondence and this proof of Cantor's theorem is also based on one-to-one correspondence. So whichever cardinality the set is, we can prove the power set of that set is larger than itself in terms of its own cardinality.*

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: Cantor's proof is not based on contradiction.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Thanks for informing me. Wikipedia lists the proof as a contradiction. However, it also notes that "the version of this argument he gave in that paper was phrased in terms of indicator functions on a set rather than subsets of a set. He showed that if f is a function defined on X whose values are 2-valued functions on X, then the 2-valued function G(x) = 1 − f(x)(x) is not in the range of f." As I am no expert on this matter, I am afraid that I cannot decide whether to defer to your judgement. Modified the answer to remove the indication that this was Cantor's original proof.